# Vite and PostCSS issue, Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css, postcss, vite

Everything was working fine, next day I'm getting an error `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`, the Chrome console tap was showing the error `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` a file with a name `${mod.url}`);`  which is points to the source file and the code is:

```
var createContext = (ctx) => {
  ctx = Object.assign({
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: "development"
  }, ctx);
  if (!ctx.env) {
    "development" = "development"; // <-- pointing to this line
  }
  return ctx;
};
```

after checking I found that file is `node_module/postcss-load-config/index.js`, and code part:

```
    /**
 * Builds the Config Context
 *
 * @param  {Object} ctx Config Context
 *
 * @return {Object} Config Context
 */
const createContext = (ctx) => {
  /**
   * @type {Object}
   *
   * @prop {String} cwd=process.cwd() Config search start location
   * @prop {String} env=process.env.NODE_ENV Config Enviroment, will be set to `development` by `postcss-load-config` if `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `undefined`
   */
  ctx = Object.assign({
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV
  }, ctx)

  if (!ctx.env) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development' // <-- HERE!
  }

  return ctx
}
```

I delete the directory `node_module`, delete the docker container and image, I did update the `package.json` dependencies and devDependencies, all of this did not solve the issue.
Also, I remove the `postcss`, the result is the same. The site is developed with Vite, Vue and Tailwindcss latest version

For me this is a big challenge, so would someone kindly help me out of this?

Thanks,

Comment: Without more details, it seem that you are bundling a package that shouldn't be bundled. As a hint, are you sure your IDE hasn't included an automaticaly generated `import` ? I mean, eg: while typing `foo..` and [ENTER], the ide could generate a `import { foo } from ...` and will throw an error.

Comment: Which bundle?
The IDE WebStorm is generating the importing by itself, missing import will results in a different error.

Comment: I am **not talking about missing import**, but **added import that shouldn't be added**. It happen for example in VSCode. **And if WebStorm generate itself the import, then I bet that my other comment answer your question**. The "bundle" thing I am talking about is for example if you include a package that can't run in the browser, it could lead to an issue like this.

Comment: I think Vite is bundling `postcss`, I'm searching how to disable this.

Answer (score 1):

I remove code, then it works

```
import { createLogger } from 'vite'
export createLogger
```

change this to

```
export const logger = console.log.bind(console)
```

I found that I used some `node utils` in broswer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this happens when your code editor automatically adds import statements when you did not want it to. The same thing happened to me. I guess it could happen if you added an import statement on accident by yourself. I removed the erroneous import statement and now the error is gone.